# Cases when f(x)g(x) is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Prove or produce a counterexample for the following;
>   $(i)$ Suppose $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that whenever $g:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then so is the product $fg$. Then $f$ is continuous.
>   $(ii)$ Suppose $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that there exists a non constant continuous function $g:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the product $fg$ is continuous. Then is $f$ is continuous.
>   $(iii)$ Suppose $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that for all discontinuous functions $g:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , the product $fg$ is continuous. Then $f$ is continuous.

Now from what I have learnt, I know that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous respectively then $fg$ is continuous, I have not come across case where $fg$ is continuous and one of the two functions is not. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to answer your remark "I have not come across case where $fg$ is continuous and one of the two functions is not. Is this possible?" Yes, it is certainly possible. Here is an example: Let $g: (a, b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be _any_ discontinuous function. And let $f=0$ (identically zero function, i.e. $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in  (a, b)$). Then, $g$ is not continuous, but $fg=0$ is continuous.

Comment: I will add to @Prism's absolutely correct comment, that if $fg$ is continuous and if one of $f$ or $g$ is everywhere non-zero and continuous, then the other will be continuous.

Comment: For part (i), consider the inclusion of $(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For part (ii), pick some $c \in (a, b)$, let $g$ be 0 between $(c, b)$ and let $f$ be continuous everywhere except some $c'$ in $(c, b)$. For part (iii), take $g$ to be $0$ everywhere except at some $c \in (a, b)$, where it is $1$ and take $f$ to be $1$ everywhere except at $c$, where it is 0.

Answer (score 1):

(i)  is true (take $g$ constant equal to $1$).

(ii) is false. Counterexample : take $g(x)=0$ when $x<0$ and 
$g(x)=x$ when $x \geq 0$, $f(x)=1$ when $x<0$, $f(x)=0$ when
$x\geq 0$.

(iii) is true, much for the same reason as (i). Let $(c,d)$
be any nonempty, strict open subinterval of $(a,b)$. Then 
there is a $g$ that is equal to $1$ on $(c,d)$, and discontinuous
at some point out of $(c,d)$. So we see that $f$ must be continuous
on $(c,d)$, for any $c,d$ as above. So $f$ must be continuous.

Comment: For (i) $g$ should be the identity and not constant.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I think the constant function $\textbf{1}$ works. It is multiplication of functions here, not compositions, right? So $f\cdot \textbf{1} = f$.

Comment: Ah you're right!@Prism